# SFINAE enable_if enable constructor with pre c++11

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, clang++

I have two different versions of my constructor (one for gpu's and one for cpu's), but the rest of the class is nearly the same for both versions.

I want to enable the cpu-variant of this class by an SFINAE enable_if statement.

The problem is, that I need to compile it without C++11 and with clang++.

The code below is working, but it generates me five warnings:

```
warning: default template arguments for a function template are a C++11
      extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
```

Is there a way, to use sfinae without the need to compile the c++ code with standard C++11 and without the c++11 warnings?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

enum arch_t{cpu, gpu};

template<bool B, class T=void>
struct enable_if {};

template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };

template<typename T1, arch_t arch>
class data {
    public:

    template<arch_t a=arch, typename enable = typename enable_if<a==cpu, void>::type, typename tmp = enable>
    data(void)
    {
        std::cout << "-CPU()" << std::endl;
    }

    template<arch_t a=arch, typename = typename enable_if<a!=cpu, void>::type>
    data(void)
    {
        std::cout << "-GPU()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    data<int,gpu> gpu_data;
    data<int,cpu> cpu_data;
}
```

Expected (and also real) Output: 
-GPU()
-CPU()

I use clang++-3.8 for compilation.

Comment: [`boost::enable_if_c`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/enable_if.html)?

Comment: You could also use tags and overload the constructors on which tag to use.

Comment: boost::enable_if_c is a good replacement for my enable_if definitions, but it leads to the same warnings, because of my owful template<...> code before the constructor. but you are right, boost is better than my own enable_ifs.

Answer (score 1):

Proposing this as an alternative solution.

Instead of using SFINAE we can use tags instead.  Here, a tag is a empty struct whose name acts as a piece of information(a tag).  We can then overload functions(this includes constructors) using the tag since it is a type.  So in this case we could have something like

```
struct cpu_arch_t {} cpu_arch;
struct gpu_arch_t {} gpu_arch;

template<typename T1>
class data {
public: 
    data(cpu_arch_t)
    {
        std::cout << "-CPU()" << std::endl;
    }

    data(gpu_arch_t)
    {
        std::cout << "-GPU()" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And then we can use it like

```
int main()
{
    data<int> gpu_data(gpu_arch);
    data<int> cpu_data(cpu_arch);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the propose, for this minimal example it is a much better approach, but I am planning a class which is working for both cuda and cpu code, and there are some methods (other than constructor and destructor) which are also different in both implementations.

In this case, i either have to tell on each method-call the tag (which is annoying and error phrone (if you call it with the wrong param)) or i save in a member variable if this class instance is for cpu or gpu usage or i do this whole by inheritance.

but in terms of overhead and usage-simplicity, sfinae would fit perfect.

Comment: @byteunit No problem.  I just figured I should give you more than just a comment so you could decide how you want to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Non exactly what you asked (and a little silly solution, I suppose) but... if you can accept that your constructor receive a mandatory dummy argument (of undefined type), you can activate SFINAE on a second optional parameter.

The following is a working example

```
#include <iostream>

enum arch_t{cpu, gpu};

template <bool B, typename T = void>
struct enable_if
 { };

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T>
 { typedef T type; };

template <typename T1, arch_t arch>
class data
 {
   public:
      template <typename T>
      data (T const &, typename enable_if<arch==cpu, T>::type * = 0)
       { std::cout << "-CPU()" << std::endl; }

      template <typename T>
      data (T const &, typename enable_if<arch!=cpu, T>::type * = 0)
       { std::cout << "-GPU()" << std::endl; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   data<int,gpu> gpu_data(0);
   data<int,cpu> cpu_data("abc");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum arch_t{cpu, gpu};

template<arch_t, arch_t>
struct arch_tag { };

template<arch_t arch>
class data {
private:
public:

  data(arch_tag<cpu, arch>) {
     std::cout << "-CPU()" << std::endl;
  }

  data(arch_tag<gpu, arch>) {
    std::cout << "-GPU()" << std::endl;
  }
};
struct data_tag:arch_tag<cpu, cpu>, arch_tag<gpu, gpu> {};

int main(){
    data<cpu> c = data_tag();
    (void)c;
    data<gpu> g = data_tag();
    (void)g;
}
```

You do have to initialize `data<gpu>` with `data_tag`, but only the appropriate one is ever called.